# Git submodule status of a branch

Tags: git

I know i can get the submodule status at my current git revision with `git submodule status --cached`

What I'd like to do though is get this information for an arbitrary branch *without* having to first check out that branch/commit.

Similarly, it would be great to be able to do a `git diff <commit> --submodule`(this is made up syntax) or something like that to just see the submodule commit differences between two arbitrary commits.

A normal `git diff` does show that a submodule has changed but it doesn't indicate
Is such a thing possible?

The closes command I can find is: `git submodule summary -n 1 <commit>` though I'm not interested in the commits that encompass the changes, just the commit reference differences.

Thanks

Comment: I often just `cd` into that submodule's directory and run git commands as you would if it weren't a submodule. Does that help?

Comment: I know I can do that but it doesn't help me much here. I essentially want a way to quickly check that branch x's submodules' pointers match that of branch y's. Sure, I can check out the other branch and do a `git submodule status` cd into the submodule as you say but it seems like there should be an easier way and to be fair git submodule summary does seem to give me the information I need

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you want the submodule hash ID stored in a superproject commit, but if so, use `git rev-parse`. For instance, the submodule hash ID for module `sub/mod` in the *current commit* is `git rev-parse HEAD:sub/mod` while the submodule hash ID for the same path in the tip commit of branch `br` is `git rev-parse br:sub/mod`. The part before the colon is anything acceptable as a commit hash ID finder, and the part after the colon is the path to the submodule.

Comment: @torek - yes that's right, the idea is to have a command that can spit out the differing submodule hash IDs of the submodules for different superproject branches/commits. The `git submodule summary` command I mentioned in the question is almost exactly what I want and to be honest, it's probably adequate for my purposes with the `-n 1` switch.

Comment: OK, well, you can construct your own command (or alias) out of `git rev-parse`, or by using `git submodule summary` with appropriate options.